# dataframe.coalesce(10).write writing 1 file in S3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We are running the following code to write a table to S3:

```
dataframe.coalesce(10).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(destination_path)
```

When I check S3, it has only 1 parquet file. How can I write it to 10 files?

Answer (score 2):

Use repartition if you want to increase number of partitions. Coalesce only decreases the number.

```
dataframe.repartition(10).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(destination_path)
```

Comment: what if I have more than 10 partitions already?

Comment: `repartition` works for increase or decrease in number of partitions. `coalesce` only works for decrease, but it's more efficient than `repartition`

Comment: when I look at the query plan, I see `Scan JDBCRelation(FilePageMetadata) [numPartitions=150]`
shouldn't the coalesce(10) split it into 10 files?

Comment: that number is only true after reading the data. after operating on the dataframe you may end up with fewer partitions